# Android how to change Imageview into another Imageview when clicked within the Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

For example, this is Frag_one.java . I have 2 images, when i click on image1, it will display image1 and some description within this fragment.

[image]

Anyone can help? thx

Here is the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/animal0"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onclick_animal0" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/animal1"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_1"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: please attach related code too?

Comment: work with visibility , show and hide on click

Comment: @JhamanDas can you be more specific? thx

Comment: @gosulove yourImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); and for textView yourTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);